# Find coordinates of intersection

Tags: trigonometry, transformation

The question says "The line with equation $y = - \sqrt{3}$ intersects the graph at points A and B, find coordinates of point B." I worked out that the graph formula is $y = 2\cos(2x)$ and I think I'm supposed to use simultaneous equations but i wasn't sure how to solve $2\cos(2x) = - \sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2\cos(2x) = - \sqrt{3}\tag{1}$$

Recall the identity 
$$\cos(2x) = 1-2\sin^2(x)$$
Then $(1)$ becomes 
$$2-4\sin^2(x)=-\sqrt{3}$$
$$\implies x=\pm \sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\cfrac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}}\right)=\pm 75^{\circ}$$

To verify. From $(1)$ $$\cos(2x)=\frac{- \sqrt{3}}{2}\tag{2}$$

Insertion of $75^{\circ}$ into $(2)$ yields $$\cos(150)=\frac{- \sqrt{3}}{2}$$ 
and since $\cos (2x)$ is even such that $\cos(2x)=\cos(-2x)$ $$\cos(-150)=\frac{- \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Do you know an angle with cosine equal to $\dfrac{\sqrt 3}2$?

When you've written the equation in the form $\;\cos 2x=\cos\alpha$, the general solution is
$$2x\equiv \pm\alpha\mod2\pi\iff x\equiv\pm\frac\alpha2\mod\pi.$$

Comment: Is the angle 30 degrees?

Comment: Would the angle be 30 degrees for point A then since it is cos2x, I multiply 30 by 2 to get 60 for point b?

Comment: Yes, or $\dfrac\pi6$ in radians. Now you have to solve $\cos3x=-\dfrac\sqrt 32$. Once you have a solution, say $\alpha$, you must solve $\cos y=\cos\alpha$, the $2x=y$. There is a double infinity of solutions.

Comment: @Bernard Good idea starting them with that hint, I just blazed in and solved it, but your approach was better so (+1).

Comment: @BLAZE: Thanks. What I don't understand is why there should be only $2$ solutions? I guess the O.P. forgot some requirements about $x$.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, you're right there was probably a range for $x$ omitted